# Replacing NAs in a dataframe based on a partial string match (in another dataframe) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na, string-matching

Goal: To change a column of NAs in one dataframe based on a "key" in another dataframe (something like a VLookUp, except only in R)

Given df1 here (For Simplicity's sake, I just have 6 rows. The key I have is 50 rows for 50 states):

| Index | State_Name | Abbreviation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | California | CA |
| 2 | Maryland | MD |
| 3 | New York | NY |
| 4 | Texas | TX |
| 5 | Virginia | VA |
| 6 | Washington | WA |

And given df2 here (This is just an example. The real dataframe I'm working with has a lot more rows) :

| Index | State | Article |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | Texas governor, Abbott, signs new abortion bill |
| 2 | NA | Effort to recall California governor Newsome loses steam |
| 3 | NA | New York governor, Cuomo, accused of manipulating Covid-19 nursing home data |
| 4 | NA | Hogan (Maryland, R) announces plans to lift statewide Covid restrictions |
| 5 | NA | DC statehood unlikely as Manchin opposes |
| 6 | NA | Amazon HQ2 causing housing prices to soar in northern Virginia |

Task: To create an R function that loops and reads the state in each df2$Article row; then cross-reference it with df1$State_Name to replace the NAs in df2$State with the respective df1$Abbreviation key based on the state in df2$Article. I know it's quite a mouthful. I'm stuck with how to start, and finish this puzzle. Hard-coding is not an option as the real datasheet I have have thousands of rows like this, and will update as we add more articles to text-scrape.

The output should look like:

| Index | State | Article |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TX | Texas governor, Abbott, signs new abortion bill |
| 2 | CA | Effort to recall California governor Newsome loses steam |
| 3 | NY | New York governor, Cuomo, accused of manipulating Covid-19 nursing home data |
| 4 | MD | Hogan (Maryland, R) announces plans to lift statewide Covid restrictions |
| 5 | NA | DC statehood unlikely as Manchin opposes |
| 6 | VA | Amazon HQ2 causing housing prices to soar in northern Virginia |

Note: The fifth entry with DC is intended to be NA.

Any links to guides, and/or any advice on how to code this is most appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create create a regex pattern from the `State_Name` and use `str_extract` to extract it from `Article`. Use `match` to get the corresponding `Abbreviation` name from `df1`.

```
library(stringr)

df2$State <- df1$Abbreviation[match(str_extract(df2$Article, 
               str_c(df1$State_Name, collapse = '|')), df1$State_Name)]
df2$State
#[1] "TX" "CA" "NY" "MD" NA   "VA"
```

You can also use inbuilt `state.name` and `state.abb` instead of `df1` to get state name and abbreviations.

---

Here's a way to do this in `for` loop -

```
for(i in seq(nrow(df1))) {
  inds <- grep(df1$State_Name[i], df2$Article)
  if(length(inds)) df2$State[inds] <- df1$Abbreviation[i]
}
df2

#  Index State                                                                      Article
#1     1    TX                              Texas governor, Abbott, signs new abortion bill
#2     2    CA                     Effort to recall California governor Newsome loses steam
#3     3    NY New York governor, Cuomo, accused of manipulating Covid-19 nursing home data
#4     4    MD     Hogan (Maryland, R) announces plans to lift statewide Covid restrictions
#5     5  <NA>                                     DC statehood unlikely as Manchin opposes
#6     6    VA               Amazon HQ2 causing housing prices to soar in northern Virginia
```

Comment: So I was playing around with this code snippet, and it works for a more simplistic dataframe. However, for the dataframe I am working on, I keep getting Null errors. Is there a way where I can create a loop (most likely a for) through each state in df1 (df1$State_name) then write in the correct abbreviation in df2$State based on the article name?

Essentially, the same result, but with a loop. Thank you so much for leading the way, though!

Comment: @llew88 See the updated answer to do this with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not as concise as above but a Base R approach:

```
# Unlist handling 0 length vectors: list_2_vec => function()
list_2_vec <- function(lst){
  # Coerce 0 length vectors to na values of the appropriate type: 
  # .zero_to_nas => function()
  .zero_to_nas <- function(x){
    if(identical(x, character(0))){
      NA_character_ 
    }else if(identical(x, integer(0))){
      NA_integer_
    }else if(identical(x, numeric(0))){
      NA_real_
    }else if(identical(x, complex(0))){
      NA_complex_
    }else if(identical(x, logical(0))){
      NA
    }else{
      x
    }
  }
  # Unlist cleaned list: res => vector
  res <- unlist(lapply(lst, .zero_to_nas))
  # Explictly define return object: vector => GlobalEnv()
  return(res)
}

# Classify each article as belonging to the appropriate state: 
# clean_df => data.frame
clean_df <- transform(
  df2,
  State = df1$Abbreviation[
    match(
      list_2_vec(
        regmatches(
          Article, 
          gregexpr(
            paste0(df1$State_Name, collapse = "|"), Article
          )
        )
      ),
      df1$State_Name
    )
  ]
)

# Data: 
df1 <- structure(list(Index = 1:6, State_Name = c("California", "Maryland", 
"New York", "Texas", "Virginia", "Washington"), Abbreviation = c("CA", 
"MD", "NY", "TX", "VA", "WA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <- structure(list(Index = 1:6, State = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
Article = c("Texas governor, Abbott, signs new abortion bill", 
"Effort to recall California governor Newsome loses steam", 
"New York governor, Cuomo, accused of manipulating Covid-19 nursing home data", 
"Hogan (Maryland, R) announces plans to lift statewide Covid restrictions", 
"DC statehood unlikely as Manchin opposes", "Amazon HQ2 causing housing prices to soar in northern Virginia"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```